# EAD = Drawn amount + Undrawn amount * CCF?

Tags: credit-risk, basel, exposure

I am pretty sure the following is true
$$
\text{EAD} = \text{Drawn Amount} + \text{Undrawn Amount} \times CCF
$$
where $\text{CCF}$ is the credit conversion factor. It means if an overdraft line is drawn to 500 EUR & its limit is 1000 EUR with CCF = 0.5, EAD is 750 EUR.

Unfortunately, I have a really hard time finding a reference for that.

**Is there any Basel paper or similar which shows that the equation above holds or possibly an alternative version if my formula is incorrect?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equation is right. There are 2 ways to write EAD:

1. EAD = Drawn + *a* x Undrawn; or
2. EAD = *a* x Limit.

In both equations, *a* is called *CCF* but it is derived/estimated differently depending on which equation you use.

You can refer to the paper "*[EAD Estimates for Facilities with Explicit Limit](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-33087-9_10)*" by Moral.

Comment: Thanks @nyk. To conclude, there is no industry standard and both can be possible.

Comment: @PalimPalim Theoretically there is no difference between the 2 equations.  In practice, corporate/commercial product guys would prefer your version since undrawn, which could be referred to as "headroom", is explicitly included in the equation.

Comment: but using my example numbers first equation: `500 + 500 * 0.5 = 750` and 2nd equation `1000 * 0.5 = 500`. What am I missing here? and here are ccfs https://www.bis.org/bcbs/publ/d424_hlsummary.pdf so which equation shall I use here?

Comment: As mentioned, in both equations, the "parameters" are called _CCF_ but they are derived/estimated **differently**. Probably the example you chose confused you.  If you look carefully, the _CCF_ in your example is a percentage/fraction of **undrawn**, which turns out to be [fortunately/unfortunately] 50%. When you applied this value of _CCF_ in the second equation of course it won't work.

Comment: Thanks @nyk. The paper states that the first version here, 2nd version in the paper is the one applied by Basel and hence the one which is relevant for me.